# T-SQL: Query to eliminate non-unique results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to select the create date for the most recent request # for each unique business unit. Because there are more unique create dates then there are business units, I get non-unique business units in my business unit column. I don't need all create dates, just the most recent one.

If you look at the CTE in v2, I want the most recent `CreateDate` for each value returned from the CTE.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Version 1:

```
SELECT 
    SQ.[Business Unit Impacted] [BU], 
    COUNT(RD.RequestID) [ReqCount], 
    (SELECT TOP 1 RD.CreateDate) [Create]
FROM 
    REP_RequestData RD
LEFT JOIN 
    REP_StandardQuestionResponses SQ ON SQ.RequestDataId = RD.Id
WHERE 
    RD.ProductID = 'Firewall.Change.Request'
GROUP BY 
    SQ.[Business Unit Impacted], RD.CreateDate
```

Version 2:

```
WITH D AS 
(
    SELECT 
        SQ.[Business Unit Impacted] [BU], 
        COUNT(RD.RequestID) [ReqCount]
    FROM 
        REP_RequestData RD
    LEFT JOIN 
        REP_StandardQuestionResponses SQ ON SQ.RequestDataId = RD.Id
    WHERE 
        RD.ProductID = 'Firewall.Change.Request'
    GROUP BY 
        SQ.[Business Unit Impacted]
)
SELECT 
    D.BU,
    D.ReqCount, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 RD.CreateDate) [create]
FROM 
    D
LEFT JOIN 
    REP_StandardQuestionResponses SQ ON SQ.[Business Unit Impacted] = D.BU
LEFT JOIN 
    REP_REQUESTDATA RD on SQ.RequestDataId = RD.Id 
WHERE
    RD.ProductID = 'Firewall.Change.Request'
GROUP BY 
    D.BU, D.ReqCount, RD.CreateDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly you just need the latest date so it's a matter of grouping only by BU and obtain the max(date):

```
SELECT 
    SQ.[Business Unit Impacted] [BU], 
    COUNT(RD.RequestID) [ReqCount], 
    MAX(RD.CreateDate) [Create]
FROM 
    REP_RequestData RD
LEFT JOIN 
    REP_StandardQuestionResponses SQ ON SQ.RequestDataId = RD.Id
WHERE 
    RD.ProductID = 'Firewall.Change.Request'
GROUP BY 
    SQ.[Business Unit Impacted]
```

Comment: This is what I needed.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In Version 2, you need to add a where clause inside of your subselect statement (select top 1 RD.CreateDate) to limit the return to the Business Unit returned on the same line along with an order by to get the latest CreateDate. It would look something like the code below:

```
(select top 1 RD.CreateDate where RD.BU = D.BU order by RD.CreateDate desc)
```

That should return the latest CreateDate based on the Business Unit.